# Limiting App Engine Flex to internal access only without App Engine Firewall?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Let's say I'm deploying a GAE Flex app and I want to restrict access to be only internal. Since GAE Flex is just a wrapper on GCE, according to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#network_settings), in the `app.yaml` file I can specify a VPC under `name` which will launch the instance into the specified VPC.

If the VPC is set up to only allow internal access, do I need to do any additional configuration of App Engine firewall rules to ensure this consistency?

More broadly speaking, what does the App Engine Firewall do differently than a VPC's Firewall rules? Does App Engine Firewall override the firewall rules set by a VPC?

Comment: App Engine Flex instances should follow the Firewall rules applied to the VPC they belong but nevertheless make sure to run some tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to your broader question about the difference between the two, you should bear in mind that VPCs allow for a wider variety of approaches to configuring your internal access, including not just [firewall rules and routes but also network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/how-to). The App Engine firewall permits only configuration of an [ordered list of rules that can allow or deny access from the specified IP address or ranges.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls#structuring_firewall_rules)

Both will need to be configured correctly in order to control access and ensure that your application can send and receive traffic in the desired way.

Answer (score -1):

I would encourage you to checkout Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.  It's a free service from GCP.

Cloud IAP lets you establish a central authorization layer for applications accessed by HTTPS, so you can use an application-level access control model instead of relying on network-level firewalls.

When an application or resource is protected by Cloud IAP, it can only be accessed through the proxy by members, also known as users, who have the correct Cloud Identity and Access Management (Cloud IAM) role.

When you grant a user access to an application or resource by Cloud IAP, they're subject to the fine-grained access controls implemented by the product in use without requiring a VPN. When a user tries to access a Cloud IAP-secured resource, Cloud IAP performs authentication and authorization checks.

https://cloud.google.com/iap/